# Prove if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then $\gcd(a \mod m,m)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then $\gcd(a \mod m,m)=1$.

Is there some simple elegant way of proving the above statement?

I prove it by noting $div(a,m)=div(a\mod m,m)$, but it is a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

A more general property: 
$$\operatorname{gcd}(a,m)=\operatorname{gcd}(m,a\mod m)$$
This property is the basis of Euclidean algorithm, and it has a simple proof:

If $a \mod m=r$, then $a=qm+r$ and $r=a-qm$. Then the set of common divisors of $a$ and $m$ and the set of common divisors of $m$ and $r$ are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Write $a = q \cdot m + a \bmod m$, clearly any common divisor of $a$ and $m$ must divide $a\bmod m$

Comment: What about the other way ?

Comment: The only candidate is 1 by $\gcd(a, m) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

If $(a,m)=1$. Dividing $a$ into $m$ we get $a=mq+r$ where $0<r<m$. We must prove that $(r,m)=1$.

By contradiction. Let $(r,m)=d>1$. So $d\mid r, d\mid m$ and we have $d\mid m, d\mid a=mq+r$. So $1<d\mid(a,m)$. We get contradiction. Q.E.D.